# css text animation not stopping

Tags: css, css-animations

I'm using a simple top-to-bottom vertical css text scroll animation and want it to stop on the last keyframe word (everyone). I've added the 'forwards' animation-fill-mode but nothing appears after it plays through once. Code: https://codepen.io/oconnellsail/pen/MZmgbo

```css
    /*Vertical Sliding*/
.slidingVertical{
    display: inherit;

}
.slidingVertical span{
    animation: topToBottom 7.5s linear 0s 1 forwards;
    -ms-animation: topToBottom 7.5s linear 0s 1 forwards;
    -webkit-animation: topToBottom 7.5s linear 0s 1 forwards;
  color: #13b2cf;
    opacity: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute; 
}
.slidingVertical span:nth-child(2){
    animation-delay: 2.5s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 2.5s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 2.5s;
}
.slidingVertical span:nth-child(3){
    animation-delay: 5s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 5s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 5s;
}


/*topToBottom Animation*/
@-moz-keyframes topToBottom{
    0% { opacity: 0; }
    5% { opacity: 0; -moz-transform: translateY(-50px); }
    10% { opacity: 1; -moz-transform: translateY(0px); }
    25% { opacity: 1; -moz-transform: translateY(0px); }
    30% { opacity: 0; -moz-transform: translateY(50px); }
    80% { opacity: 0; }
    100% { opacity: 0; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes topToBottom{
    0% { opacity: 0; }
    5% { opacity: 0; -webkit-transform: translateY(-50px); }
    10% { opacity: 1; -webkit-transform: translateY(0px); }
    25% { opacity: 1; -webkit-transform: translateY(0px); }
    30% { opacity: 0; -webkit-transform: translateY(50px); }
    80% { opacity: 0; }
    100% { opacity: 0; }
}
@-ms-keyframes topToBottom{
    0% { opacity: 0; }
    5% { opacity: 0; -ms-transform: translateY(-50px); }
    10% { opacity: 1; -ms-transform: translateY(0px); }
    25% { opacity: 1; -ms-transform: translateY(0px); }
    30% { opacity: 0; -ms-transform: translateY(50px); }
    80% { opacity: 0; }
    100% { opacity: 0; }
}
```

```html
<h1 class="sentence">
    <div class="slidingVertical">
      <span>Your struggling student</span>
      <span>Your child</span>
      <span>Everyone</span>
    </div>
<br>can be a math person.</h1>
```

Comment: What _should_ appear after it play through once?

Comment: "Everyone" should appear/remain. The code from Nimit Shah solved it (below). Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add one more animation `topToMiddle`.

```
@-webkit-keyframes topToMiddle{
    0% { opacity: 0; }
    5% { opacity: 0; -webkit-transform: translateY(-50px); }
    10% { opacity: 1; -webkit-transform: translateY(0px); }
    100% { opacity: 1; }
}
```

and add it to `.slidingVertical span:nth-child(3){.... .... animation-name: topToMiddle;}`

```css
/*Vertical Sliding*/
.slidingVertical{
 display: inherit;
 
}
.slidingVertical span{
 animation: topToBottom 7.5s linear 0s 1 forwards;
 -ms-animation: topToBottom 7.5s linear 0s 1 forwards;
 -webkit-animation: topToBottom 7.5s linear 0s 1 forwards;
  color: #13b2cf;
 opacity: 0;
 overflow: hidden;
 position: absolute; 
}
.slidingVertical span:nth-child(2){
 animation-delay: 2.5s;
 -ms-animation-delay: 2.5s;
 -webkit-animation-delay: 2.5s;
}
.slidingVertical span:nth-child(3){
 animation-delay: 5s;
 -ms-animation-delay: 5s;
 -webkit-animation-delay: 5s;
  animation-name: topToMiddle;
}


@-webkit-keyframes topToMiddle{
 0% { opacity: 0; }
 5% { opacity: 0; -webkit-transform: translateY(-50px); }
 10% { opacity: 1; -webkit-transform: translateY(0px); }
 100% { opacity: 1; }
}
/*topToBottom Animation*/
@-moz-keyframes topToBottom{
 0% { opacity: 0; }
 5% { opacity: 0; -moz-transform: translateY(-50px); }
 10% { opacity: 1; -moz-transform: translateY(0px); }
 25% { opacity: 1; -moz-transform: translateY(0px); }
 30% { opacity: 0; -moz-transform: translateY(50px); }
 80% { opacity: 0; }
 100% { opacity: 0; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes topToBottom{
 0% { opacity: 0; }
 5% { opacity: 0; -webkit-transform: translateY(-50px); }
 10% { opacity: 1; -webkit-transform: translateY(0px); }
 25% { opacity: 1; -webkit-transform: translateY(0px); }
 30% { opacity: 0; -webkit-transform: translateY(50px); }
 80% { opacity: 0; }
 100% { opacity: 0; }
}
@-ms-keyframes topToBottom{
 0% { opacity: 0; }
 5% { opacity: 0; -ms-transform: translateY(-50px); }
 10% { opacity: 1; -ms-transform: translateY(0px); }
 25% { opacity: 1; -ms-transform: translateY(0px); }
 30% { opacity: 0; -ms-transform: translateY(50px); }
 80% { opacity: 0; }
 100% { opacity: 0; }
}
```

```html
<h1 class="sentence">
    <div class="slidingVertical">
      <span>Your struggling student</span>
      <span>Your child</span>
      <span>Everyone</span>
    </div>
<br>can be a math person.</h1>
```

Test it [here](https://codepen.io/nimittshah/pen/QzBbRp)

Comment: Glad it helped you. Please accept the answer so it can help other folks. :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need create a animation to last span like that: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KbBpqM

and use:

`animation-iteration-count: 1`

Comment: Thanks for the response!